# Change list entries based on condition in python

Tags: python, list

I want to "draw a picture": I create a list with entries of o´s. Then I want to go through each element of the list to weigh a random number against a previously chosen 'density' number.  If the number is smaller than my previously chosen density, then I want that entry to be replaced by a T.. Then it's the next element's turn with a new random number.

This is my code so far:
It either gives all o's or just a single T.

```
import random

list = []
number_of_entries = 5
density = 0.5

list.append(["o"]*number_of_entries)  # ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o']

for index, entry in enumerate(list):
    if random.random() < density:    
        list[index] = "X"
```

Comment: Your list initially contains exactly one element, which is itself a list.  Your `for` loop is therefore executing only one time.  You want `.extend()` instead of `.append()`, and you *definitely* want a different name for it than `list` because you're overwriting a rather important built-in name that way.

Comment: You meant to write: `list.extend(["o"]* ...`. Or better yet, forget about all that extending and appending: `list = ["o"] * number_of_entries`.

Comment: Which ever way you choose, please don't use `list` as a variable name. You will end up having far too much *fun* chasing down strange errors later. Maybe something like: `picture = ["o"] * number_of_entries`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `list` (by the way don't use reserved words as variables names)  has two nested lists and that's the problem, try this:

```
import random

number_of_entries = 5
density = 0.5
alist = ["o"] * number_of_entries
for index, entry in enumerate(alist):
    if random.random() < density:
        alist[index] = "X"
        
print(alist)
```